# PSPDFKit add network image into scrollview like pdf page

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pspdfkit

I'm using PSPDFKit in my app. I want to load remote images async with the framework, cause there are both images and normal files in my app. I have tried convert imageData into PDFDataProvider, which cannot be Asynchronous. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Author of PSPDFKit here. Please contact us for feature requests directly, we only rarely monitor StackOverflow - that's not the right platform to provide support for commercial products.

That being said, the `PSPDFViewController` is designed to present PDF files - we don't have immediate plans to add support for other file types.